# don't get result after send content

Tags: android

i want to send text view content to another activity, and count token thats textview content.

this my code
in first activity(sender)

```
public class Tokenizing extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
Button button;
TextView tv;

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE ="TEST";       
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, Detail.class);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView7);
    String message = tv2.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

in second activity

```
public class Detail extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private static final String FILENAME = null;
private static final String TAG = null;
Button button8;
Button button9;
Button button10;
TextView tvsblm;
TextView tvssdh;
TextView prepoword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

    TextView tvsblm = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
    Intent intent;
    intent = getIntent();
    String Message = intent.getStringExtra(Tokenizing.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(Message);
    int len = st.countTokens();
    System.out.println(len);
    result.append(len+'\n');

    tvsblm.setText(result);
```

but i dont get result anything in textview tvsblm
I do not want to use a button to send the contents of the first activity because I use to go to another activity
if there is something wrong with my coding?
or is there another way I can use

Comment: where have you declared key "EXTRA_MESSAGE", when you are putting the value in intent?

Comment: Why don't you just use `tvsblm.setText(Message)` ? (by the way, that name doesn't follow the Java convention of names)

Comment: @amitsingh ye i declase "EXTRA_MESSAGE" wait i update first activity code.

Comment: @NKN i want count token berfore show thats content

Comment: Have you tested whether the count is the expected? I'd suggest using: `tvsblm.setText(result.toString());`

Comment: @abooo from where are you calling sendMessage() ?

Comment: @amitsingh i realy confuse about this, i just want to send textview7 content and next i want to countstring textview7 content and show that result at tvsblm.
can you help me how to do it?